# How to replace a string with square brackets using javascript replace function?

Tags: javascript, replace, str-replace

I have a string [TEST][NO CHANGE][TEST][NOW][TEST] in which [TEST] should be replace with 'replaced', and the result should be replaced[NO CHANGE]replaced[NOW]replaced.

I have Tried the following ways, nothing worked.
1. str.replace(/'[TEST]'/g, 'replaced'); 
2. str.replace(/[TEST]/g, 'replaced');
3. str.replace('/[TEST]/g', 'replaced');

```
var str = "[TEST][NO CHANGE][TEST][NOW][TEST]";
var resultStr = str.replace(/'[TEST]'/g, 'replaced');
```

Actual String: [TEST][NO CHANGE][TEST][NOW][TEST]
After Replacing: replaced[NO CHANGE]replaced[NOW]replaced

Comment: You need to escape square brackets `/\[TEST\]/g`

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression in `replace` is looking for the string `'[TEST]'` surrounded by those single quotes and is looking to match any of the characters in TEST because you didn't escape the brackets. Try this regular expression instead:

```
var resultStr = str.replace(/\[TEST\]/g, 'replaced');
```

Answer (score 1):

`[]` has a special meaning in regex, which means [**character class**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), if you want to match `[]` you need to escape them

```js
var str = "[TEST][NO CHANGE][TEST][NOW][TEST]";
var resultStr = str.replace(/\[TEST\]/g, 'replaced'); 

console.log(resultStr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to update using Below snippet.

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.split(search).join(replacement);
};
var str = "[TEST][NO CHANGE][TEST][NOW][TEST]";
var result = str.replaceAll('\[TEST\]','replaced')
console.log(result);
```

> replaced[NO CHANGE]replaced[NOW]replaced

[image]

Src : [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)